# When is the Lorenz system the Lorenz attractor?

Tags: definition, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

I am currently studying chaos theory but am unsure what the difference is between the Lorenz system and the Lorenz attractor. Is the Lorenz attractor just the solution of the Lorenz system with $\beta=8/3,\sigma=10,\rho=28$? Or does the name 'Lorenz attractor' apply to more general parameter values?

Answer (score 1):

The attractor is a set of points in $\Bbb{R}^3$. You can see the definition of an **attractor** here: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Mathematical_definition). A quick summary is: For the parameter values you've given, solutions are *attracted* to the set -- if you imagine time going to infinity, then the solutions get closer and closer to the attractor.

The system is the set of equations itself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I understand that an attractor is a subset of phase space but is the 'Lorenz attractor' only for the aforementioned parameter values?

Comment: Ah, I see -- yes, I believe so, since those are the values Lorenz chose.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that not all parameter values lead to chaotic behavior.